# What are the available themes for Enthought Canopy Editor>

Tags: editor, enthought, canopy

What are the available themes for Enthought Canopy Editor? The default one I find via 'preference.ini' is 'linux'. I am looking for a black(ish) front end.

Answer (score 1):

The only acceptable values are 'lightbg', 'linux' or 'nocolor' none of which provides a dark background.